# Spaces in data.frame in R Sweave

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I'm making a table in R Sweave using a data frame, but I don't know how to create spaces between the titles, they come out is separated by points. Is there a command that solves this?

[image]

with the following code

[image: Code]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. Instead of posting an image of your code, it's much more helpful to post the actual code itself, and also the R packages that are being loaded.

Comment: The "Grado de insomnio" could be "severo" managing these variables names. I will use a sort version (<6 a-z characters, without spaces), renaming only (as Alan showed)  if it is needed to produce plots or tables.

Comment: @Fran I’m not sure I agree with this. Experience has shown me that longer more descriptive names (without spaces of course) pay off in the long run especially if you return to your data after some time away. But renaming for tables and plots is almost always necessary anyway since the public face of your data needs to be understood by readers.

Comment: @AlanMunn My mistakes with variable names increases exponentially with longer names. I named it the "sausage- finger syndrome" `:(`  and spaces in names is simply annoying syntax as you must always quote the name. But there are methods to label properly variable names, so you can always remember what are exactly. For instance `label()` from `Hmisc`, `labels()` from `papeR` and `apply_labels()` from `expss`. You can use also for this `sjlabelled`, `foreing`, `memisc`, etc . An example [here].(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347548/r-assign-variable-labels-of-data-frame-columns) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R is converting your column names into valid variables, which can't contain spaces. So when you write:

```
mydf <- data.frame("Some heading"=c("One Two","Two","Three"))
```

it converts "Some heading" into `Some.heading`. To bring the space back  you need to explicitly declare names:

```
names(mydf)=c("Some heading")
```

Complete example:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
mydf <- data.frame("Some heading"=c("One Two","Two","Three"))
names(mydf)=c("Some heading")
kable(mydf,booktabs=T)
```

Produces:

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
\toprule
Some heading\\
\midrule
One Two\\
Two\\
Three\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image: output of TeX code]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me. Sometimes handling this kind of program gets you stuck on trivial things.